# How to edit home dir of docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-machine

i launched `docker-machine -d VirtualBox docker-app` machine. The thing is, I wanted to mount some folder from my host machine. Therefore, I manage to add a specified folder (in VirtualBox) in shared folders and set a mounting point to '/home/docker/somefolder' to have quick access from home directory to this. However, after the restart, a folder appeared but in `~/` localization not in mounting point, I previously specified. Why is this happening? Second question: Is it possible to change the HOME directory (~/ instead of default /home/docker/)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is just a note, docker machine provides a layer between docker and the file system.

The point is that anything you would run in the virtual machine can be mapped with your host system by using [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). A volume, could point to any path in your host system.

In order to share a concrete folder (maybe a folder shared in the network or any other special case) with all docker containers, you have the option to mount that folder into all of them, and so, have live updates in their content.

An explanatory approach could be:

```sh
alias dm='docker-machine'

dm start name_of_vm
eval $(dm env name_of_vm)

docker run -v /path/to/local:/inner/path -it container1 bash
docker run -v /path/to/local:/inner/some -it container2 bash
docker run -v /path/to/local:/inner/path -it container3 bash
```